# Well the workspace panel suddenly disappeared and workspace indicator came on top bar

Tags: gnome, 20.04, indicator, workspaces, panel

So basically there was an update and when I restarted after the update, the workspace panel on the right side of activities panel was gone and I had to enable the workspace indicator in the top bar to navigate w/o using shortcuts. Also ever since the panel disappeared in the activities, the orientation of the windows are weirding out.
Is there any way I can bring it back to activities as a panel?
[image: the orientation of the windows are weird and the workspace panel at the right dissapeared]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Sanxchep Sharma have you disable the gnome-shell-extensions call
Horizontal workspaces it could be the issues that cause the workspace to suddenly disappeared

Hope it helps you

Best regards